# Set boolean to false when pressing every other key except enter button vue.js

Tags: vue.js, boolean

Hey guys so I currently have an input form and would like to set showTag to false when pressing any other button besides enter. For example, after I press delete button or the letter q I would like the showTag boolean to be set to false. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

```
<input type="text" v-model="msg" class="form-control m-0" placeholder="Filter by tag" @keyup.enter= "showTag=true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I mean, you could just handle all keyups, and check for the key code, since the passed event should be a regular javascript event like any other.

```
<input type="text" v-model="msg" class="form-control m-0" placeholder="Filter by tag" @keyup="onKeyup" />
```

...

```
methods: {
    onKeyup(event) {
        showTag = (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13)
    },
},
```

Comment: If you don't have to support older browsers, `event.key === "Enter"` is more expressive.